# Moto E changes to wrong time or wrong time zone

Tags: clock, date-and-time, time-zones, motorola-moto-e

My dad is using a Motorola Moto E, running Android 4.4.4 (not rooted).

He has noticed that it frequently displays the wrong time or date. Sometimes this is just the wrong time zone, other times it is completely the wrong time or date. I have set the time, date and time zones correctly, but they still seem to end up wrong again.

This seems to happen whether the options to use network provided time and network provided timezone is enabled or not.

Maybe it is due to him accidentally pressing the buttons to change this. But I have asked him about this, and he says he isn't doing this as far as he is aware. Or is the phone changing the time for some other reason?

Anyway, how to prevent this, and keep the time correct?

Comment: You could ask your dad to set the correct time, and don't touch it for the next 24 hours (or less if he MUST). This filters user error vs. the phone being buggy. You could also disable automatic time

Comment: Yes, could try that sometime. Though it seems a bit random - it may keep the correct time for a few weeks, or it may change after a day or so.